# How scheduling a date with task parameter on Databricks Job Workflow

Tags: databricks

[Exemple Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk2tR.png)

Is it possible to use a parameter to schedule specific notebooks to be run using the parameter in the Task?

For example I would have two notebooks, one that will run daily, and one monthly.

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameter for such case would be not a best practice.

For your scenario it would be better to have two Workflows with different schedule.

However if you really need to run the notebook based on parameter, you can do something like this in the called entry notebook:

```
scheduling_time = dbutils.widgets.get('scheduling_time')
if scheduling_time = 'daily':
  dbutils.notebook.run("Daily Notebook", 60)
elif scheduling_time == 'monthly':
  dbutils.notebook.run("Monthly Notebook", 60)
```